# Visual Source Safe Automated Commit

Tags: version-control, automation, visual-sourcesafe

I am currently attempting to set up an automated add/checkout/checking script using MS Visual Source Safe via command line.  Online documentation is... lacking... and I was hoping that someone else had tried doing something like this in the past.

Before going any further, I am well aware that there are other, better alternatives to VSS, so please don't give "use SVN" as an answer.

The files I've got are a scripted version of our database schema, and looks like this in the repo:

$/project_name/DBScripts/servers/databases/object_types, where object_types are Tables, StoredProcedures, etc.

I am attempting to do the following:

1- Script all database object to files.  This part is done and working correctly.
2- Add all new files to repo.
3- Commit all files that have changed.  Make sure files do NOT remain checked out or read-only.

EDIT 2:

Removed old code again.  Included current code below.  Add works correctly, but the checkout command does NOT work on any files that were changed locally.

In this context, if I were to modify stored proc A, script it to file, then try running the batch commands below, all procs BUT A will be checked out.

I've included 2 examples of the checkout command.  Neither is working...

```
set PATH=%path%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe
set SSDIR=repo_path

cd DBScripts/server/database/StoredProcedures
ss cp $/project/DBScripts/server/database/StoredProcedures

for %%F in (*.*) do ss add %%~nF%%~xF -C- -I-N -K- -W
for %%F in (*.*) do ss checkout $/project/DBScripts/server/database/StoredProcedures/%%~nF%%~xF -C- -G- -M- -L+
ss checkout $/project/DBScripts/server/database/StoredProcedures *.* -C- -G- -M- -L+ -Vltemp
for %%F in (*.*) do ss checkin %%~nF%%~xF -C- -K- -P $/project/DBScripts/server/database/StoredProcedures -W

cd ../../../..
```

Note: SourceSafe's "-R" command is inconsistent.  I'd rather loop through all subfolders manually and do "for %%F in (*.*)" commands.

Comment: Would you please tell us more about "which absolutely does not work"? Do you get any error message? Or the commands don't meet your requirements?

Comment: While I appreciate the response, the errors I've gotten through my various iterations of the code are of no real use - I'm not looking to correct some bug in my code.  Rather, I simply need help structuring a proper ss.exe command.  Also, this should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: A few threads I've read while looking up solutions suggest that SourceSafe is potentially buggy, and an upgrade may be required.  Really hoping that isn't the case here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reason is the checkin command is executed before prior add/checkout commands are finished. Try checking if add is successful before the checkout command, and checking if checkout is successful before the checkin command.